# Using serial ports, I get an error: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serial-port

I know this question has been asked before but none of the existing answers solved my problem. I have a WinForms Application which communicates with a number of devices, takes data and writes them to a file.

It opens GPIB and Serial port communications and at the end closes all of them. I use `this.Dispose()` and `this.Close()` to make sure that memory is released (at least I think the memory is released). However, next time I run it, after several hours I get the error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

If I run it again the crash time becomes shorter and shorter as if something is accumulating in memory. I copy parts of my code that seem to be related to this issue. Am I making any mistake in memory consumption?

**What I tried:**

Added `this.Dispose()` and the `Close()` functions to close the ports (initially I forgot to add them). But still did not help. I also tried to restart my computer before each run, yet it did not help either.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //GPIB and serial ports
    SerialPort Arduino;
    SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
    private Device DMM1, DMM2, DMM3;
    private Address DMM1_Address, DMM2_Address, DMM3_Address;
    private Address[] Address_List = new Address[3];
    private AddressCollection GPIB_Adds;
    Board GPIB = new Board(0);
    //Timers
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer fire_time = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer measurement_time = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer preparation_delay = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    public Form1()
    {
        // ...some code
    }

    private void InitializePorts()
    {
        // ...ports are initialized here
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       preparation_delay.Interval = 1000;
       preparation_delay.Tick += new EventHandler(start);
       preparation_delay.Start();

       measurement_time.Interval = 60000;
       measurement_time.Tick += new EventHandler(stop);

       fire_time.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) * 1000;
       fire_time.Tick += new EventHandler(FIRE);
        }
    }

    private void start(object obj, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
        measurement_time.Start();
        fire_time.Start();
        preparation_delay.Stop();
        preparation_delay.Tick -= new EventHandler(start);
        //Here I try to annihilate the event handler in fear of staying in memory
    }

    private void FIRE(object obj, EventArgs e)
    {
        string p = //Reads data from device
        string[] k = //Reads data from device
        string t = //Reads data from device
        Write_to_Text(t, p, k);
    }

    private void stop(object obj, EventArgs e)
    {
        fire_time.Stop();
        measurement_time.Stop();
        progress.Stop();
    }

    private void Write_to_Text(string time_date, string PRC_Reading, string[] DMM_Reading)
    {
        string string_to_save =  ...some string

        try
        {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@filename, string_to_save);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            Arduino.Close();
            GPIB.Dispose();

            measurement_time.Stop();
            fire_time.Stop();
            this.Dispose();
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.Close();
        Arduino.Close();
        GPIB.Dispose();

        this.Dispose();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't think you need to (or should) dispose a windows form in .NET. Not sure if that is the issue maybe someone with more experience with this kind of error has more insight.

Comment: Please mention what you have tried to avoid redundant answers.

Comment: @user I just did.

Comment: I don't see a reason to add and remove those tick handlers.  Just add them once in the constructor.  You don't have to call this.Dispose and this.Close in the FormClosing event.  It's already in the process of doing that.  Do you know which line causes the exception?

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for your comment. I guess exception occurs during the Write_to_Text() method.

Comment: What makes your Fire method get called?  Is Fire a tick event?

Comment: @LarsTech Oops! My bad. It is eventhandler for fire_time event. I forgot to add it here but it is already in my code. See new edit.

Comment: This is probably just a typo in the question, but you have an extra `}` in `button1_Click`.

Comment: Any chance you are still reading from the device when the next tick event fires?  Use a variable to prevent that: `bool readingDevice = false;`  Use it in that event method.

Comment: @LarsTech That could be possible. I will apply your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For native NET objects in principle you don't need to call Dispose explicitly (the finalizer will do that), but if you have some external objects accessing external resources (GPIB?) you have to be careful. What I see is that if there is an exception in Write_To_Text you will call GPIB.Dispose twice, and also that it can be called before the timers effectively stop. Make sure that there will be no call to any Gpib function after you dispose it (for example set a flag that will be checked before calling Gpib functions).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you find yourself manually calling the `Dispose()` function, that's a bit of a code smell... an indication something is not right.

Instead, learn to use the `using` keyword to create blocks that wrap disposable objects. This will help you create meaningful scope boundaries for the those objects. It also helps avoid mistakes, where `Close()` and `Dispose()` calls were not properly wrapped with a `finally` block.

In this case, the problem likely involves these code snippets:

```
this.Dispose();
this.Close();
```

Never call `Dispose()` from inside the object itself you want to dispose (except as part of implementing the core `IDisposable` pattern). Instead, it's up to the outside code to tell your object when it's finished. Here, you attempt to `Dispose()` a form *before* the `Form_Closing` method is raised (see `Write_To_Text()`), meaning the form is invalid when Form_Closing() itself tries to execute.