# Performance of memory in winforms with C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Before I open the `SaveFileDialog` Process Memory is running at 21MB and after opening the `SaveFileDialog` it jumps to 42MB and even after closing the DialogBox it does not return to the same value. 
[image]

I don't think that this is a problem of new objects created because later in the process I create more instances and memory does not change at all. I am a bit worry about the memory usage as I have had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253977/using-serial-ports-i-get-an-error-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory%22this%20problem%22) for long time now.

**Why is this happening?** or **Is this "process memory" shown in the VS has anything to do with the memory consumption of the form?** Here is my code inside the DialogBox

```
private void textBox4_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    using(SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.AddExtension = true;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
        saveFileDialog1.CreatePrompt = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
            textBox4.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {
                using(StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(filename))
                {
                    s.WriteLine(header);
                    s.Flush();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File is not accessible!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I had this program running for several hours and the value of 42MB never goes down.**

Comment: Once the window is created it uses up some memory, when it closes, it does not mean the memory used by it will be garbage collected right away. What happens if you iteratively open and close windows? Does it increase the memory usage ever so high? Or does it stay around 42 mb?

Comment: @Glubus In fact when I close the DialogBox memory usage slightly drops and if I open it again it goes up to the same value and when I close it again it goes down a bit.

Comment: Right so there you go. Apparently creating a dialog window costs a couple of MB. SInce it's a graphical element you shouldn't be surprised too much. The reason it does not disappear is because your system reserves the memory for your application. Once it needs it for something else it will automatically do it. I woudn't worry about it.

Comment: Also, the process memory is just the sum of memory used by your application (i.e. Process). Knowing this, it might become clear that once you do certain things in your application, it will increase the amount of used memory..

Comment: Your program uses far too little memory to say anything meaningful from this info, it did not even run a gen #1 collection yet.  Specific to SaveFileDialog is that it loads a large number of unmanaged DLLs into your process.  All of the shell extensions installed on the machine.  Programmers tend to have a lot of them, not always of the best quality.  Unloading them is technically possible but tends not to work well in practice, this is completely beyond your control.  At any rate, nothing to see here, move on.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal and okay. It's not a new object sitting in memory. Instead, in order to use the `SaveFileDialog`, the program had to load a few additional assemblies from the system. So this new memory isn't part of the program's operation memory or working set... it's part of the program executional code itself.

The program won't unload these assemblies automatically unless the system is under actual memory pressure, where that memory (or memory address space) really is needed for something else. After all, you might need them again and taking the time to unload them would just slow the program down while it happens.

This is unrelated to the linked question. The issue in the link question is entirely about security boundaries, and has nothing to do with using too much memory.

Comment: Regarding the linked question: It seems to be due to memory issues and not the security reason necessarily. Sometimes I run the same program for days without any issue and sometimes it crashes after a couple of hours. For either cases data are saved on the same folder which proves that problem is not because of file access.